# How to get error message instead of stopping at breakpoint when app crashes in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I tried launching my app on my ipad and it crashed immediately. I connected my ipad to xcode to try and debug the problem.
When I run my app on my ipad through xcode the build succeeds but then stops at the splash screen. It stops at a breakpoint and gives me the following message: "WebThread (10): EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1c0867dac)".

I have tried stepping over the breakpoint, tried to get the program to continue execution and deactivated breakpoints in the debug menu.

I would like to get past that breakpoint someway and just let the app crash while testing so I can get some kind of error message for what is causing this. Does anybody have an idea of how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if this will help you or not but have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100285/ios-uiwebview-crash-in-webthread

Comment: I don't believe this trap can be handled.  Why would you want to anyway?